# How to put a variable in a shared memory?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have a variable with a value and I want to share it with the proccesses.

Ex:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int a;
  unsigned int b;
  another_struct * c;
} struct1;
...
struct1 A ={...};
...
```

Now, I want to create a shared memory region and put the A variable in this region. How can i do this?

Comment: You should `create a shared memory region and put the A variable in this region`.

Comment: but how? shmget expecte key,size and shmflg parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared memory is an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) feature (which does not exist in [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))). It is not "provided" by the C standard.

I guess that you are coding for Linux. BTW, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Read first [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html). You'll need to synchronize, so read also [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).

You'll get some shared memory segment into a *pointer* and you'll use that pointer.

First, open the shared memory segment with [shm_open(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html):

```
int shfd = shm_open("/somesharedmemname", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0750);
if (shfd<0) { perror("shm_open"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on that `shfd`:

```
void* ad = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct1), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 
                shfd, (off_t)0);
if (ad==MAP_FAILED) { perror("mmap"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then you can cast that address into a pointer:

```
struct1* ptr = (struct1*)ad;
```

and use it. (Don't forget to `close`).

BTW, you don't and **you cannot put a *variable* into a shared memory**. You get a ***pointer*** to that shared memory and you use it, e.g. `ptr->a = 23;`

Of course, don't expect the same shared segment to be mapped at the same address (so you can't *easily* deal with pointer fields like `c`) in different processes. You probably should avoid pointer fields in shared `struct`-s.

Notice that C variables exist only at compile time. At runtime, you only have locations and pointers.

PS. Shared memory is a quite difficult [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism. You should perhaps prefer [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s and you'll need to multiplex using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Comment: yes I know, but i want to know if there is any way to put a variable into the shared memory. I can create a shared memory region but i couldn't put a variable in it.

Comment: You can't put a *variable* in a shared memory. You should use *pointers*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Beej's Guide to IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/shm.html).

I would basically treat the whole shard memory segment as a `void*` that you can place items at. You could use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), of `string.h`, to copy A into your shared memory space. However your pointer in `A` would become invalid and cause a segfault if you attempted to use it in another process connected to shared memory segment.

Comment: The question is tagged `C`.

Comment: @WeatherVane memcpy exists in the `string.h`, but it's still valid. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I was referring to `std::memcpy`