# putting an array of structs into shared memory in unix so that it can be accessed by a client program

Tags: c, arrays, unix, struct, shared-memory

So i'm currently trying to code in unix using shared memory and the fork() function, I have an array of 10 structs and I would like to put that array into shared memory so that it can be accessed by a client program. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to do this.

the code I currently have is:

```
//  Compiler Directives


//  Standard Library Inclusions
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
//Other Inclusions

struct strProcess 
{
  int nPriority;
  int nPid;
};
//  Function Prototypes (if not included within a header file)
int frand (int nInput);
int finval (int nInput);
void fsortasc(struct strProcess pArray[],int nInput);
//  Main
int main(void)
{
// Variable Declarations
int     nShmid,i,arraySize,nRpriority,j, nInput;
key_t   nKey;
char    *ptrshm, *ptrs;
int     nSize;
pid_t   pid; 
struct  strProcess pArray[10];
struct  strProcess *Array;

Array = pArray;
// Code start

nKey = 5678;
FILE *f = fopen("logfile.txt", "w");

if (f == NULL)
{
      printf("Error opening file!\n");
      exit(1);
}

printf("please enter the amount of processes to create for this cycle between 1 and 10 \n");
scanf("%d",&nInput);
if (nInput <= 0 || nInput > 10)
{
  nInput = finval(nInput);
}
printf("%d", nInput);

nSize = sizeof(pArray) * 10;
 //create segment
if ((nShmid = shmget(nKey,nSize, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) <0)
{
      perror("shmget");
      exit(1);
}
printf("segment created \n\n");
fprintf(f, "shared memory segment created");

Array *pArray = shmat(shmid,NULL, 0);
if (Array* pArray (-1)) 
{
      perror("shmat");
      exit(1);
}
printf("segment attached \n\n");
fprintf(f, "shared memory segment attached");

for(i = 0 ; i < nInput; i++)
{
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
      Array[i].nPid = getpid();
      nRpriority = frand(nInput);
      Array[i].nPriority = nRpriority;
      printf("print job created with Pid %d and priority number %d", 
      getpid(), nRpriority);
      fprintf(f, "print job created with Pid %d and priority number %d", 
      getpid(), nRpriority);
    }
}

fprintf(f, " %d processes have been created", nInput);
fsortasc(pArray, nInput);   /*sort array into ascending order by nRpriority values*/

// Function Definitions - in alphabetical order
int finval (int nInput)
{
while(nInput <= 0 || nInput > 10)                               
{
    printf("please enter a number between 1 and 10 \n");
    scanf("%d", &nInput);                                       
} 
return nInput;                                                
}

int frand (int nInput)
{   
int nRand;
nRand = (rand() % nInput)+1;                  /*set nRand == a random number 
                                               inbetween nInput and 1*/
return nRand;                                 /*return the random number*/
}

void fsortasc(struct strProcess pArray[],int nInput)  
{
struct strProcess temp;     /*temporary storage for elements being swapped*/
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < nInput - 1; i++)                                 
{
    for (j = 0; j < (nInput - 1-i); j++)
    {
        if (pArray[j].nPriority > pArray[j + 1].nPriority)                      /*if the current element is greater than the next element*/
        {
            temp = pArray[j];                                                   
            pArray[j] = pArray[j + 1];                                          
            pArray[j + 1] = temp;                                               
        }                                                                       
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code you posted represent something you have that compiles? (because as is, what you have posted does not)

Comment: the code I have does not compile, i'm just trying to work out how to put the array in the shared memory that i create

Comment: See this answer _[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923618/645128)_. It goes into sufficient detail to get you started.  BTW, this is actually a very useful site for getting answers from people, but as with anything, you should know the _[rules of the road](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ to maximize your experience here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a variable in a shared memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923518/how-to-put-a-variable-in-a-shared-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have an array of 10 structs and I would like to put that array into shared memory ?** It's very simple, first create `array 10 struct variable` and then create the `shared memory` using `shmget` of required `size` and then `attach` that `shared memory` with `pointer` and finally `copy` array of 10 structs into pointer attached with `shmat`. I added below simple code to understand your requirement.

```
typedef struct company {
        int emp_id;
}cmp;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
        cmp cmp_info[10];
        int shm_id, sze = sizeof(cmp_info) ,i;
        /* I have an array of 10 structs -- with some data like emp_id*/
        for(i=0 ;i<10 ;i++) {
        printf("\n enter emp % Id \n",i);
        scanf("%d",&cmp_info[i].emp_id);
        }
        /* create the shared memory of 'sze' size. */
        shm_id = shmget(10,sze, IPC_CREAT | 0664);
        perror("shmget");
        /* attach the shared memory with shm_id */
        cmp *shm_ptr = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
        perror("shmat");
        /* I have an array of 10 structs and I would like to put that array into shared memory  */
        shm_ptr = cmp_info;//now shared memory contains array of 10 struct data 

        /** print using shm_ptr to verify **/
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        printf("Employee[%d] Id is : [%d]\n",i,shm_ptr[i].emp_id);
        }
        /* once above things are done clients program can read from shared memory */
        /** finaly de-atach the shared memory */
        shmdt(shm_ptr);
}
```

Below snapshot is for your code, Explanation is in comments.

```
struct strProcess {
        int nPriority;
        int nPid;
};
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
        // Variable Declarations
        int     nShmid,i,arraySize,nRpriority,j, nInput;
        key_t   nKey;
        char    *ptrshm, *ptrs;
        int     nSize;
        struct  strProcess pArray[10];//array of 10 structure
        struct  strProcess *Array;
        //Array = pArray;
        nKey = 5678;
        FILE *f = fopen("logfile.txt", "w");
        if(f == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file!\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        nSize = sizeof(pArray);
        //create segment
        if((nShmid = shmget(nKey,nSize, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
                perror("shmget");
                exit(1);
        }
        else {
                perror("shmget");
                fprintf(f, "\n shared memory segment created\n");
        }
        Array  = shmat(nShmid, NULL, 0);
        perror("shmat");
        /** loop to create exaCtly 10 process */
        nInput = 10; /** call finval function **/
        for(i = 0 ; i < nInput; i++) {
                if(fork() == 0) {
                        srand(getpid());
                        Array[i].nPid = getpid();
                        nRpriority = rand()%10 + 1;//putting random no b/w 1 to 10..u can call your function also
                        Array[i].nPriority = nRpriority;
                        fprintf(f, "\nprint job created with Pid [%d] and priority number [%d]\n",
                                        Array[i].nPid, Array[i].nPriority);
                        break;//must to avoid repeating
                }
                else {
                        ;//parent does nothing
                }
        }
        shmdt(Array);
        //fprintf(f,"\n total [%d] processes have been created\n",nInput);
        /* call fsortasc(pArray, nInput); */
        fclose(f);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: but would i not need a key to access the shared memory in the client

Comment: Yes created shared memory will be identified by `shmid` and `key`,  you can check using `ipcs  -m` command. `Key` is not required because once data is copied into pointer(`shmat` address) you can use that `pointer` to access shared memory in the client.

Comment: Thank you for the help. if I wanted to put a char into the shared memory in front of the array. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Hi sorry to keep bothering you but, there was an issue with receiving the array in the client program. i tried to print it out but all I am getting is ones I was wondering if you could help

Comment: @iAnwar sorry is not required bro. I don't know how you are receiving array in client program so I can't guess. Can you modify your question and put that particular portion of code where you are not receiving not correctly ?